# Top level UIView in .xib file (in a "Universal" device project) defaults to 600w x 600h - can this be changed somehow?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, xib

Please see attached screenshot:

[image: UIView in .xib file]

When creating a .xib file with only a UIView in it `Width` and `Height` settings default to 600 each, and are greyed out. Is there any way to adjust these numbers please? Thank you.

Context: I have a UITableViewCell that may feature one of a number of different UIViews embedded in it, on the fly, and these will only ever be of a set height (70 or 128).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

In Attribute inspector you need to change  the simulated Metrics size to Freeform. Then you can adjust the size of uiview.

Answer (score 1):

In the Attribute inspector you have to change the size to freeform. Then in the size inspector you can change the width and height size.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Yogesh, but I'll accept the other answer as it came first.

Answer (score 1):

Try following solution. You need to change size Inferred to freedom.

[image]